# How can i reset arrylist in each loop of for?

Tags: java

I have an Integer arraylist . I want clear it in each for and then fill it again.My code is:

```
private static int myMethod(int prim){

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> number = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> sublist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int x = 2; x < prim; x++ ){

        for (int power = 0; power < prim - 1; power++){ 
            // in this loop sublist 
            //will be fill
            int i=(int)((Math.pow(x, power))%prim);
            sublist.add(i);     
        }

        number.add(sublist);

    }
}
```

prim is for example 7 ,so i want have number array list so this =>

```
[[1,2,4,1,2,4][1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5]...]
```

but number arraylist has this form:

```
[[1,2,4,1,2,4,1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5][1,2,4,1,2,4,1, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5]]
```

Please help me :(

Comment: plz write in better form.Could not understand at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just clear `sublist`; you have to create a new `sublist` each time through the loop.

```
for (int x=2;x<prim;x++ ){
    sublist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int power=0;power<prim-1;power++){ // in this loop sublist //will be fill
        int i=(int)((Math.pow(x, power))%prim);
        sublist.add(i);     
    }

    number.add(sublist);

}
```

When you add `sublist` to `number`, you add a *reference*; `sublist` is *not* copied.  If you just call `sublist.clear()`, you'll add an empty list to `number` each time through.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please accept it by clicking the check box next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the list in for loop...

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>  number=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
       for (int x=2;x<prim;x++ ){
    // create sublist rather than outside the loop
    ArrayList<Integer> sublist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int power=0;power<prim-1;power++){ // in this loop sublist //will be fill
                int i=(int)((Math.pow(x, power))%prim);
                sublist.add(i);     
            }

            number.add(sublist);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>  number=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> sublist=null;
    ArrayList<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int x=2;x<prim;x++ ){
     sublist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int power=0;power<prim-1;power++){ // in this loop sublist //will be fill
             int i=(int)((Math.pow(x, power))%prim);
            sublist.add(i);     
        }

        number.add(sublist);

        }
```